# Compile AWS SDK (.NET) for the Xamarin's Mono Touch / Android Framework

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have a project that I am willing to start using [Xamarin's Mono Framework](http://xamarin.com/) since it supports .NET language to write native code to multiple mobile plataforms.

I am not sure how the mono compiler actually works but I know that I have to actually compile source code onto it's compiler in order to use the .dll on mono projects. We can't simply use .dll compiled onto the .NET assembly on Mono Projects.

Since I am also willing to use the some of the [AWS Services](http://aws.amazon.com), thus, I need it's SDK compiled for the mono. There's a [implementation](https://github.com/xamarin/amazon) of the AWS SDK compiled for the mono framework, but it is old as hell.

I have just discovered that the [AWS SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net) is open source, and thus I am considering trying to compile it onto the Xamarin's mono compiler to see if I can use it on my projects.

Any insights here? Will it work ? Why?

Comment: SO works best when you ask specific, targeted questions.  "Any insights here?" and "Why?" are broad questions that invite opinion and discussion.  If you're interested in a discussion, you'd be better off asking on Xamarin's forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't compile the latest AWS SDK for the Xamarin/Mono framework as it is.

There are at the moment some libraries that the framework does not support (System.Diagnostics, System.Net are some of those).

The only way to make it work at the moment is to rip off all the references to any unsuported library on the AWS SDK source code, but since the code is huge and so deep, it ends up being an impossible task.

Unfortunately i couldn't find any way to make it work.

On the other hand, as a "Workaround" you can implement your own Wrapper around the AWS API's you need (which is what the SDK ends up being) if you take care of the requests assembling, signing and building correctly and retrying it will work as the SDK would.

Comment: still no solution to this?!

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin has an official release of [AWS SDK for MonoTouch and MonoDroid](https://github.com/xamarin/amazon). Last commit was a year ago though.

Yes, since the [AWS SDK For .Net](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net) is open source, you may just grab it and compile it against mono compiler.

Comment: It might be a rare case that the AWS SDK for .Net uses some methods which are not implemented in Mono. http://go-mono.com/status/

Comment: I have downloaded the AWS SDK source code on GitHub and tried to compile it. It works if the source is put on a standard C# class library, but it fails if its either a PCL or an android library. Would you mind helping me ? I Really need a hand on this, im heavily depending on the AWS SDK

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins Hi, if you have a specific problem, please post it as a question. :)

Comment: I am too lost to even try to formulate my problem as a question. Nevermind, i will try to contact their support